# Последовательное выполнение $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!
Каким образом можно заставить следующий код работать последовательно?

```
$.each(this.db, function(index, element)
{
    $.get("calc/" + element.id, function(data)
        {
            $('#result').append('<div>' + data.result</div>');
        }, "json" );
});
$('#result').append('<div>done</div>');
```

На данный момент, получается, что отправляется одновременно n-ое количество запросов на сервер и не дожидаясь ответа выводится "done", после чего в "случайном" порядке ответы от сервера.

Comment: Вот как будто для вас написали недавно http://habrahabr.ru/company/mailru/blog/269465/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `Deferred` (переходите на темную сторону силы :))

```
var chain = $.Deferred().resolve();
$.each(this.db, function(index, element) {
    chain = chain.then(function() {
        // Самая соль этих строк в return - он возвращает Deferred объект,
        // к которому применяется следующий .then()
        return $.getJSON("calc/" + element.id).then(function(data) {
            $('#result').append('<div>' + data.result + '</div>');
        });
    });
});
chain.then(function() {
    $('#result').append('<div>done</div>');
});
```

PS. Ну и раз вы собираетесь использовать тип JSON, я поменял `$.get({dataType: "json"})` на `$.getJSON()`

Ссылки по теме:

- Документация [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (по-английски)
- [Статья](http://habrahabr.ru/company/bankrot-pro/blog/230441/) на Хабре (по-русски)
- Гугл с запросами [JavaScript Promise](https://google.com/search?q=JavaScript%20Promise) и [jQuery Deferred](https://google.com/search?q=jQuery%20Deferred)

Answer (score 0):

```
var db = this.db; //в верхнем scope, чтобы был доступ из функции
function fetchResult() { //для рекурсии
    if (db.length>0) { //если есть что-то еще в массиве
        var element = db.shift(); //забираем первое значение
        $.get("calc/" + element.id, function(data) {
            $('#result').append('<div>' + data.result + '</div>');
            fetchResult(); //ответ пришел - следующая "итерация"
        }, "json" );
    } else {
            $('#result').append('<div>done</div>');
    }
}
```