# Последовательный запуск асинхронных функций в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть три функции `funk1()`, `funk2()`, `funk3()`. Как сделать чтоб вторая функция запускалась только после того как выполнится первая, а третья запускалась строго после выполнения второй.

Есть код который делает анимацию (`Animatein()`), потом подгружает данные, потом опять анимацию(`Animatein()`). Нужно, чтоб он это делал последовательно.

Вот код:

```js
var time = 0;
var dfs = 15000
$.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
  time = 100;
  x = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.each(data['date'], function(key, val) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          Animatein()
          $('body h1').empty().append(val.chef);;
          $('body h2').empty().append(val.dolznost);;
          $('.topick').empty().append(val.anotation);
          $('.date_block').empty().append(val.dataRel);

          $('.left_block').attr('src', val.url + ".jpg");;
          Animatein()
        }, dfs)
        dfs += 18000;

      });
      x();
    }, time = 100)

  };
  x();
});
```

Comment: А что вы сами пробовали? И что у вас не получилось?

Comment: @ Vartlok , Собственно получилось. Я навешал таймеры на каждую функцию, и выполнил тогда когда нужно. Теперь хочу сделать по умному. Записать как говорит человек ниже не приведет к нужному результату.

Comment: @Dementiy1999 пожалуйста, пишите более развернутые вопросы. опубликуйте Ваш код в вопросе.

Comment: А интересует как можно отследить выполнение функций. Если успешно выполнилась , то навешать обработчик например. Ток не могу понять как это правильно сделать...

Comment: Как вариант, можно прям в сами функции добавить вызов, и там же проверка что функция отработала как надо.

Comment: Прочитайте про промисы. Недавно был похожий вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462101

Comment: @Dementiy1999,  ваша функция `Animatein()` -- асинхронная?

Comment: Dmitriy Simushev, Она выполняется на протяжении одной секунды. Сдвигает обект влево.

Comment: @Dementiy1999, и? Оно делает это синхронно или асинхронно?

Comment: Dmitriy Simushev, Она синхронная. отложного запуска на ней нет. Выполняется сразу.

Comment: @Dementiy1999, а зачем вам `setTimeout` внутри `each`?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, Система такая приехала плашка, подгрузилась инфа на ней, потом плашка уехала. Таймер для того чтоб инфа менялась на плаше через равные промежутки времени. Собственно и инимация должна выполнятся в те промежутки.

Comment: @Dementiy1999 и последний вопрос: количество AJAX запросов ограниченно?

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, функция рекурсивно подружает данные ajax. То есть не ограничено.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В оригинальном вопросе слишком уж много лишнего (не относящегося к сути вопроса) кода, поэтому опишу упрощенную ситуацию.

Пусть есть несколько повторяющихся AJAX запросов. Эти запросы должны выполняться последовательно неограниченное количество раз, при этом каждый следующий должен начинаться только после того, как обработаются данные из предыдущего запроса.

Фактически, есть три красивых решения этой проблемы:

1. Использовать функции обратного вызова.
2. Использовать обещания (Promises).
3. Использовать генераторы.

Здесь я опишу только первый способ решения проблемы. Возможно он не самый компактный и современный, но его освоение позволяет понять, как правильно работать с функциями обратного вызова в JS.

Итак, ваш код может выглядеть, например, так:

```
var run = function(url, timeout, callback) {
    // Функиця, которая вызывается обработчиком полученных данных после окончания обработки.
    var done = function() {
        // Перезапускаем AJAX запрос через некоторое время.
        setTimeout(req(), timeout);
    };

    // Функция, которая будет получать данные с сервера.
    var req = function() {
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            // ВАЖНО: кроме данных, обработчику передается функция,
            // которая должна вызываться по завершению обработки.
            callback(data, done);
        });
    };

    // Инициализируем последовательность выполнения.
    req();
};

run('data.json', 500, function(data, done) {
    // Проводим какие-нибудь манипуляции с полученными данными.
    // Для примера, используем асинхронное действие по таймеру.
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.dir(data);
        // ВНИМАНИЕ: Эта функция обязательно должна быть вызвана.
        done();
    }, 100);
});
```

Для того, чтобы не писать весь код из примера выше, можно использовать различные библиотеки, например [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). Тогда весь код свернется в:

```
async.forever(function(done) {
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        // ....
        // Повторяем через 500 мс.
        setTimeout(done, 500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант: http://jsfiddle.net/uznxb20r/

```
function funk1 (callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("funk1 complete!");

        if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function funk2 (callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("funk2 complete!");

        if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function funk3 (callback) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("funk3 complete!");

        if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

var num = 0;
var arrs = [];

function callAsync (arr) {
    if (arr) {
        arrs = arr;
    }

    if (arrs[num]) {
        arrs[num](callAsync);
        num++;
    } else {
        arrs = [];
        num = 0;
    }
};

callAsync([funk1, funk2, funk3, funk2, funk1]);
```