# Последовательное выполнение функций. Алгоритм

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Задача. Реализовать последовательное выполнение произвольного количества функций. Если точнее, то каждая следующая функция должна начинать свое выполнение только по завершении другой.

Неочевидный момент. Что, если функции выполняются асинхронно, откладывая свой запуск? Каким образом отследить завершение выполнения такой функции.

```
'use strict';
let functionsToCall = [myFunc1, myFunc2, myFunc3, myFunc4, myFunc5];
sequence(functionsToCall);

function sequence(fns) {
  let sFns = fns.map(function(func, index, array) {
    if (array.length - 1 === index) return func;
    return loggingDecorator(sequenceDecorator(func, array[index + 1]));
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < sFns.length; i++) {
    if (i !== 0 && i % 2 === 1) continue;
    sFns[i]();
  }
}

function sequenceDecorator(f, afterFunc) {
  return function() {
    let res = f.apply(this, arguments);
    afterFunc();
    return res;
  }
}

// Логируем вызовы функций
function loggingDecorator(f) {
  return function() {
    console.log('Start execution');
    f.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log('End execution');
  };
}

// myFunc1, myFunc2, и т.д. - простые, однотипные функции
function myFunc1() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      console.log('%c%d', 'color: red', i);
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

Фиддл. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohbcwb5d/1/)

Comment: В общем виде похоже придется модифицировать код аиснхронных функций, потому что только они знают, что результаты получены и они завершаются. Они при завершении работы должны вызывать какую нибудь функцию-планировщик, которая будет запускать следующую

Comment: в текущем виде - никак.

Comment: Откуда в вашем примере возьмется массив аргументов (который `array`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте промисы. Например реализацию от [promisejs.org](https://www.promisejs.org/) или [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) от jQuery. Изучайте [цепочки промисов](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise#%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

В качестве примера можете рассмотреть этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/462347/177613)

Если браузер поддерживает промисы "из коробки", то сработает этот сниппет:

```js
function myFunc1(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve();
  }, 3000);
}
function myFunc2(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve();
  }, 5000);
}
function myFunc3(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resolve();
  }, 2000);
}
function log(text) {
  let logElement = document.getElementById('log');
  logElement.innerHTML += '<br />' + text;
}
function sequence(fns) {
  let chain = Promise.resolve();
  fns.forEach(function(fn) {
    chain = chain.then(function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        log('started execution at: ' + new Date().toTimeString());
        fn(resolve, reject);
      }).then(function() {
        log('stopped execution at: ' + new Date().toTimeString());
      });
    });
  })
  return chain;
}
sequence([myFunc1, myFunc2, myFunc3]);
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Минусующий, ну напишите хоть, что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Общий подход будет выглядеть следующим образом:

1. Создаете переменную состояния `State`.
2. Создаете один непрерывный цикл `while(true)` (что нежелателно) или одну функцию, постоянно вызываемую по таймеру. Внутри него/нее идет проверка условия на текущее состояние (проверка значения `State`). Например, если `State = 1`, то запускаете первую функцию `*sequence*`, а если `2-ке`, то запускаете вторую функцию `*sequenceDecorator*`. И т.д. Если равно `0` - то ничего не запускаете.
3. В начале каждой функции прописываете `State=0` (чтобы на время выполнения ее других не запускалось), ну а в конце функции (при выходе) пишите состояние для запуска следующей. Так в конце функции `*sequence*` ставите `State=2`, чтобы запустилась `*sequenceDecorator*`.

Ну и так далее по порядку.

Comment: Спасибо за идею! Хочу кое-что уточнить. Что значит: "в конце функции (при выходе) пишите состояние для запуска следующей"? Как получается, интерпретатор вызывает функцию myFunc1(дописываю, что State=0), дальше он(интерпретатор) видит setTimeout, планирует отложенный вызов, но не могу же я перед выходом просто поставить State=2, так как интерпретатор(по факту) исполнит отложенный вызов уже после того, как состояние я поменяю.

P.S. Идею я понял. Но в контексте того, что я писал раньше, судя по всеми будет сложнее что-то писать, нежели с нуля.

Comment: @chillout Так никаких исполнений этих запукаемых функций по таймеру быть не должно вообще. Я поэтому и указывал для примера не Ваши простые функции с таймером, а именно те, где у Вас его нет. Таймер (точнее SetInterval) должен быть только для одной общей функции (которая вместо цикла). Сложнее или проще использовать такой подход - не знаю. Но это не есть что-то новое. Это, так сказать, велосипед, довольно распространенный в случаях с однопоточностью.

Comment: если менять функции `myFunc1`,`myFunc2` и т.д. нельзя - то подход не сработает, так как внутри самих функций нет никаких переменных который они могут поменять, если же эти функции менять можно, то проще использовать promise, или callbacks

Comment: @Grundy я так понимаю (и судя по тому варианту этих функций, что в вопросе), что это его функции. И причин их не менять может быть только две: не хочу и не буду.

Comment: @MaxZS В принципе, все правильно. Это "в вакууме" предположение, что мануально, то есть руками, их менять не нужно. Вот и родилась идея, просто обвязки вокруг них сделать, но, как Вы объяснили, в данном случае - это не очень хорошая идея.

Во общем, это даже не касается никакой "боевой задачи". Благодарю за внимание.